selenium does not find the HTML locators of a page that I open with chrome with the ie tab extension
I have a robotframework code that opens a site in Chrome, this site is already configured to open with the ie tab extension since my company established it that way because we cannot use Internet Explorer, but when indicating in the site login to add the user to text box and password. The code gives an error since it does not find these elements
I know I can't access them because the ie tab emulates Internet Explorer and Chromedriver only manages the Chrome browser.
How can I access these elements to be able to interact with them, having the limitation of only using the Chrome browser and using the ie tab?
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}         Chrome
${DRIVER_PATH}     C:/chromedriver.exe
${USER_DATA_DIR}   /Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data
${URL}             http://siebelcrm/ecommunications_esn/start.swe?
${USER}            user
${PASSWORD}        pass

*** Test Cases ***
Abrir Navegador Chrome con Perfil Predeterminado
    ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --allow-running-insecure-content
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --disable-web-security
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    --user-data-dir\=${USER_DATA_DIR}


    Create Webdriver    ${BROWSER}    executable_path=${DRIVER_PATH}    options=${chrome_options}

    Maximize Browser Window
    Go To   ${URL}
    Input Text    id:s_wepi_1    test
    Sleep   4
    Close All Browsers

